# How to Send Whatsapp Media Using Json for Twilio Api?

Tags: wordpress, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I want to send Pdf file with message text in wordpress Using Twilio API in json format. How can i achieve it ?

To Send message on whatsapp i used below code.

https://www.wpcodetips.com/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-send-an-sms-from-wordpress-programmatically/

I want to send pdf file also with message via json . How can i achieve it with Twilio API in wordpress ?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of what you tried and describe where you are stuck?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.